# Master's degree after Bachelor in Liberal Arts and Humanities

Tags: masters, europe, changing-fields, humanities, liberal-arts

I have a question regarding a futher education after obtaining Bachelor degree in Liberal Arts and humanities. Is it feasible/possible/widespread to obtain Master's in some other specialization? Particularly I am interested in Master's in archeology or antropology (preferably in Europe).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: From modern linguistics to archeology - difficult. From history to archeology - possible. You would have to check the admission criteria of the individual programs you're targeting, though.

Comment: Often times the shift from Bachelor's programs to Master's programs has more to do with thinking skills than it has to do with content (or knowledge of facts). Master's programs aim to teach students underlying thinking skills through intensive reading and discussion. For that reason there is less need for facts than one would normally expect and therefore you may be able to handle a change of discipline.  In fact coming from a different background may give you an advantage (if you know how to use it).